# Why does docker-compose create the source directory in one syntax but not the other?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

Consider the following YAML code in my `docker-compose.yml` file that sets up volume mounting (using version 3.7), using [short form syntax](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax-3) as specified in the docs:

```
volumes:
    - ./logging:/var/log/cron
```

This maps the relative path `logging` on my host machine to the `/var/log/cron` folder inside the container. When I run `docker-compose up`, if the `logging` folder doesn't exist on my host machine, Docker creates it. All good there.

Now, if I change the above to [long-form syntax](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#long-syntax-3):

```
volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: ./logging
      target: /var/log/cron
```

Now when I run `docker-compose up`, it DOES NOT create `logging` folder if it doesn't exist on my host machine. I get

```
Cannot create container for service app: b'Mount denied:\nThe source path "C:/Users/riptusk331/logging"\ndoesn\'t exist and is not known to Docker'
```

**Does anyone know why the short form syntax creates the host path if it doesn't exist, but the long form does not and gives an error?**

Using Docker Desktop for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually a "feature" (bug) of the old `-v` syntax that they didn't want to fix because it would break all the thousands (millions?) of implementations that people created that relied on that behavior.

The newer `--mount` volume syntax that was introduced for Docker Swarm and then extended to be compatible with original Docker CLI calls, explicitly didn't reintroduce this functionality because it was "unexpected magic" that isn't really documented and shouldn't have been relied upon.